# Where JSF and struts2 fails/goods

Tags: jsf, struts2

I am begining a web system and can't decide what technology use! Struts2 and JSF (with jboss seam) are a nice choices, but I can't decide which's better. In JSF have some that I don't like, maybe its "paradigm" no action like. And Struts2, the peoples here don't use more.

The system is a map collaborative web site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used both Struts2 and JSF extensively, both are good but I would still recommend JSF. Here is why.

1. **More users**. Yes this counts; more people means its easier to get hands on new programmers.
2. **Better tool support**. IDEs like IntelliJ have very good JSF support.
3. **Facelets**. Lets face it, JSP sucks. You simply should not be allowed to write business logic inside your view code. Keeping your views in XHTML ensures that they are clean and tidy.
4. **Documentation/Books**. This might have changed, but when I was in the struts2 camp (2007/2008) the books available was few and of very poor quality. There is a good choice of JSF/Seam books.
5. **JSF2/Seam**. JSF2 is very nice (and IntelliJ 9 supports it). New scopes, such as the view scope, are really helpful (fx. if you are having a long running conversation in a flow).

If you are interested in some of the newer features in JSF2 then checkout [this](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/) blog post. Also you might want to check out **Stripes**, it is also a very nice server side web framework and finally [here](http://tinyurl.com/ykly2fp) is a very thorough (and a little old) comparison of most Java web frameworks.

Comment: Would you recommend JSF for high traffic internet facing web applications ?

Comment: @user this depends on if the site can run mostly in the client or if allot of server side processing is required. In the later example, JSF should be good.

Answer (score 4):

This a very debatable topic. I think the main advantage of Struts2, compared to JSF, is its simplicity, it is much easier to grasp. Specially for beginners in web programming, or those familiar with "action based" web frameworks (Struts 1, Webworks, Spring MVC, Stripes).
But Lars Tackmann's points are valid (though Struts2 does not force you to use JSP; and indeed it uses FreeMarker internally). It's true that Struts2 has not attained a big user base, the community (both users and developers) does not seem to be very active, and that is a big minus. JSF also has its shortcomings, I've heard (I've not used it)... as every Java web framework, it seems.